# Wait while variable does not exist MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wait, exists

I need to suspend the program until the variable is created.  I point to the data file, then open uiimport to specify the range of data. And at this moment I have to suspend the program until the variable is created.

```
%find file
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.xls;*.xlsx', 'Excel files(*.xls, *.xlsx)'},'Укажите Excel-файл с данными');
%open import wizard
uiimport(strcat(PathName, FileName));
% here i need to suspend the program until the variable is created
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify an output variable when calling `uiimport`. If you do this, no lines after your call to `uiimport` will be executed until `uiimport` has completed (the user has chosen data to import or not).

```
data = uiimport(fullfile(PathName, FileName));

% Do stuff with data
disp(data.value)
```

If for some reason, you *did* need to wait until a variable existed, you could use a `while` loop combined with `exist`, but in general this is a marker of poor program design.

```
while ~exist('variablename', 'var')
    % Do something that may define the variable
end
```

**Update**

If you're simply reading an excel file, it is likely easier to use `xlsread` to do so:

```
data = xlsread(filename, -1);
```

Comment: But the program continues to run immediately after the call to uiimport. [link](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1466457679/b4bf3cc2/13094222.jpg
)

Comment: @MaximMefodovskiy Ah ok. Yea you have to specify an output to `uiimport` as I have shown above

Comment: I try to do this. But i got different window. http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1466458008/56a547ae/13094251.jpg

Comment: @MaximMefodovskiy Yes that is prompting you to select what you want to import... you have to select what you want to import and hit `finish`. why are you using `importdata` to read a spreadsheet rather than `xlsread`?

Comment: `uiimport` useful if you need to select a specific range of data. But `xlsread` selects all data. In the "other" import window no button is available. How can I continue to import?

Comment: @MaximMefodovskiy You can specify a range to `xlsread`. Is there actually data in your file?

Comment: I do not know in advance what range of data must be selected.

Comment: I found the solution. [Function xlsread][1]. This `data = xlsread(filename,-1)` does what I needed. Thank you for the help. Add this for your answer, if u can.

  [1]: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html?searchHighlight=xlsread#bthgb2w